# mpv can't play cdrom

Tags: music-player, mpv

entering this command `mpv cdda://` starts to spin the music cd I've inserted previously but 3 secs later quits giving me this output.

```
(+) Audio --aid=1 (pcm_s16le 2ch 44100Hz)
[cdda] Switched to track 1
AO: [alsa] 48000Hz stereo 2ch s16
A: 00:00:00 / 00:00:00 (92%) Cache: 0.0s


Exiting... (End of file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not mentioning the Linux distribution you're using, or even the version of your `mpv` player but from a couple of search, it seems this is related to [this](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=766725) issue.

The following should solve this:

- Use `mpv av://libcdio:/dev/cdrom`
- Upgrade your `mpv` version (which I'll assume here that it is old or doesn't have full support for `libcdio`)
- Compile latest `mpv` with `libcdio` support. Feel free to [check](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv-build) this repository for doing so.

Comment: sorry I'm using mx linux (MX-19.4)  32 bit version ```mpv 0.32.0 Copyright © 2000-2020 mpv/MPlayer/mplayer2 projects
 built on UNKNOWN
ffmpeg library versions:
   libavutil       56.22.100
   libavcodec      58.35.100
   libavformat     58.20.100
   libswscale      5.3.100
   libavfilter     7.40.101
   libswresample   3.3.100
ffmpeg version: 4.1.6-1~deb10u1``` yeah I've tried that command but didn't work for me either.

Comment: I see. from the output of the version, you can see/notice yourself this isn't listing `libcdio`, so you should probably 1. use a different linux distro, 2. compile latest version following the link i mentioned, 3. maybe there a debian/ubuntu repo you could add with latest mpv, but I'm pretty sure it might break something if it install/overwrite the already installed ffmpeg version on mx linux... @testoflow

Comment: Do tell me if this answer resolved your issue or not if you don't mind :D @testoflow

Comment: I'm going to try to compile mpv. Thanks @Nordine

Comment: Np. And if that take too long (believe me, this can take decently long time depending on your machine, say 1 hour or less if it's fast, or 4 - 10 hour+ if it's old enough) you can always try the other things I mentioned as alternative! @testoflow